# Adding two tables with no column in common in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables my database. I just want to append these two tables. I am not able to find the solution for it

Table 1  -

```
 names
    First_name    Last_name
      Navjot        Singh
      Ram            Gopal
      Naveen         Kumar
```

Table 2 -

```
address
            address    Pin
             Delhi    90007
             Lucknow  90003
             Mumbai   60008
```

How to get the data from these two tables in the following format:

```
First_name      Last_name      address        Pin

  Navjot        Singh            Delhi       90007
  Ram           Gopal           Lucknow     90003
  Naveen        Kumar            Mumbai     60008
```

These are just sample tables. I want to do this thing on 50,000 rows. Number of rows are same in my both the tables. I have tried cross join. I have tried following sql as well:

Select * from names,address;

It increases the total number of rows. I even tried union, but it did not work.

It is something like cbind.data.frame in R. 
How to do it in mysql?
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Basically, it's not possible. You have nothing that relates a row in the first table to a row in the second.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have no column for the join.  Assuming that you have some column to specify the ordering, you can do:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
      from table1 t cross join (select @rn := 0) params
      order by t.id
     ) t1 join
     (select t.*, (@rn2 := @rn2 + 1) as seqnum
      from table2 t cross join (select @rn2 := 0) params
      order by t2.id
     ) t2
     on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

This generates a sequential key for each row in each of the tables.  This key is then used for the joins.

Comment: That's what I get for answering from my phone.  Nearly the same result

Comment: @dnapierata . . . Read the context of that statement.  This warning is actually about using variables in multiple *expressions* in the same `select`, not about reading the value from a single expression.  Although the language is a bit ambiguous, the examples are very clear that the warning applies to assigning the variable in one expression and reading the variable in another.

Comment: @GordonLinoff My mistake. After reading your statement you are in fact only evaluating one variable per `select` so the undefined nature of the way MySQL interprets variables shouldn't affect the query.

Comment: @dnapierata . . . I think the right answer is that the `:=` operator *returns* the value of the expression, rather than "reading" the variable and returning that.  This behavior is not explicitly stated in the documentation, which is a shame.  However, numerous examples in the documentation support the assignment of the result of `:=` to an alias.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier way but off the top of my head

```
Select I.*, j.* from
   (Select *, @row:@row+1 as rowid from names) I
Left join
   (Select *, @adid:@adid+1 as rowid from address) j
Using(rowid);
```

Comment: It is dangerous to use session variables in a SQL statement without initializing them.